# How can OC4J be configured to support Arabic?

Tags: java, arabic, oc4j

How can OC4J be configured to support Arabic?
some arabic contents appear as ? question marks, however in the pages that this probelm arises in it, the page encoding (**<%@ page pageEncoding="windows-1256" %>**) is set properly (I tried all possible alternative windows-1256, utf8, ... etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for adjusting OC4J configuration to support Arabic do the following:

in the OC4J Server Properties screen in the Command Line Options block add the bold options to your Java Options as follows:

Java Options= -Xms512m -Xmx512m -server
-Djava.security.policy=/u01/app/oracle/products/10gias/j2ee/OC4J_EPS/config/java2.policy
**-Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.region=AE -Duser.language=ar
-Dfile.encoding=windows-1256** -Xverify:none